# Chrome - Cross Origin XMLHttpRequest doesnt seem to work in contentscript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my background script I am injecting my contentScript as follows:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){
    if(isPDF(details))
    {   
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {file: "content.js", runAt: "document_end"}, function(result){
            if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
            {
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            }
        });
        return {
            responseHeaders: [{
              name: 'X-Content-Type-Options', 
              value: 'nosniff'
            }, {
              name: 'X-Frame-Options', 
              value: 'deny'
            }]
          };
        }
}, {
    urls: ['*://*/*'],
    types: ['main_frame']
}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

In `content.js` I have the following code:

```
function reqHandler()
{
    alert("hello");
    var imgData = "" + this.responseText;
    //document.write("" + imgData);
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'  + "" + imgData);
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

//debugger;
var PDFdata = document.body.innerHTML;  
document.body.innerHTML = "";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = reqHandler;
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:81/getImage.php", true);
xhr.send();
```

As you can see I am making a cross-origin XMLHTTPRequest here. The problem that I am facing is that the content.js script is being executed but my `reqHandler` function which should run after the completion of the xhr request is not running at all.

The alert inside it is not shown. What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**
Here is the manifest file for the extension:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },

    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "tabs",
        "webNavigation"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK only internal extension scripts that are executed in the privileged context like the background page script (not content scripts which don't have access to privileged APIs) can make Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest (more info in the [official docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)).

Invoke XHR in your background page script, [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) to the tab's content script.

- background.js:

  ```
  chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){
      if(isPDF(details))
      {   
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var tabId = details.tabId; // save id in the local context
          xhr.onload = function() {
              chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {imgData: this.responseText});
          };
          xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:81/getImage.php", true);
          xhr.send(); 

          chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {file: "content.js", ..............
  ..................
  ```
- content script:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (message.imgData) {
          document.body.innerHTML = "";
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + message.imgData;
          document.body.appendChild(img);
      }
  });
  ```